# How to play audio file on fancybox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fancybox, lightbox

I have used fancybox for my gallery. When I click the gallery image it will display image and title in lightbox, alright. But my audio file is not working.
Here is my code:

```
<a class="fancybox-thumbs" title="mytitle" data-fancybox-group="thumb"  href="4_b.jpg"
 audio-html="<audio autoplay='autoplay' controls='controls'><source src='https://archive.org/download/melody2007/bandaamorperfeito-aovivo-01-lovelouco.mp3'/></audio>"><img src="4_s.jpg" alt="" /></a>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
$('.fancybox-thumbs').fancybox({
    prevEffect : 'none',
    nextEffect : 'none',

    closeBtn  : true,
    arrows    : true,
    nextClick : true,

    helpers : {
        thumbs : {
            width  : 100,
            height : 100
        },
        title : {
            type : 'inside'
        },
        buttons : {}
    },
    afterLoad : function() {
        this.title;
    }
});
```

Comment: Is the audio file received by browser ?

Comment: define `my audio file is not working` with more info please

Comment: this is my audio file :                                   `audio-html="<audio autoplay='autoplay' controls='controls'><source src='https://archive.org/download/melody2007/bandaamorperfeito-aovivo-01-lovelouco.mp3'/></audio>"`

Comment: Actually i want to add this `audio-html` to below the image title and it should play automatically

Comment: @VadivelMuruganM `mp3` link is broken

Answer (score 1):

You can use Iframe option of Fancybox3:
http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/3/docs/#iframe

`<a data-type="iframe" data-src="http://yoursite.com/mp3/file.mp3" href="javascript:;" rel="fancybox">LINK</a>`

Answer (score 0):

```
<img class="img-fluid" src="image.png" width="100%" height="100%" alt="">
 <div class="caption">
  <h4>
    <a data-fancybox="" data-caption="" href="#myAudio1">Audio Name</a> 
  </h4>
   <audio controls id="myAudio1" style="display:none;">
    <source src="audiosource.mp3" type="audio/mp3">
   </audio>
 </div>
```

Comment: You may want to explain your answer.